# Input type date hide default value in Microsoft EDGE

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, date, microsoft-edge

On Google chrome, you can use this to hide the `dd/mm/yyyy` displayed

```
  &::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,
  &::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,
  &::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field,
  &::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
    color: transparent;
  }
```

What is the equivalent for microsoft edge ?